# Loading HTTPS website under HTTP website using iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, cross-domain

I am facing issues for my website we want to load

HTTPS website under HTTP site using iframe

when I make my HTTP site HTTPS everything works fine, but I cannot do that.

when I try to load HTTPS site under HTTP site using iframe I am getting many javascript error like 
'Call Failed: Error: Could not get access to camera/microphone'

How to solve this cross domain problem?

More Details:-

I have website which access Webcam & Microphone build under HTTPS say child.com

I have another website build under HTTP - parent.com

How I am using HTML iframe to load HTTPS website 'child.com' under my HTTP website parent.com using an iframe

this does not work as I get many javascript error complaining security issues and webcam and microphone are not accessible after including the child .com under iframe. how to resolve this crossdomain issues ?

Comment: you need to provide more detail

Comment: added more details